# Pdf is incomplete when converted from UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, pdf-generation

I need to generate a report as pdf an print it. Im generating a view with all the information and converting it to pdf and then showing the pdf file in a `UIWebView`. But when I see the Pdf file in the `UIWebView`, the file is not complete (a big part of the right area and the bot area are cut). I don't know if my `UIView` is too big when I'm converting it to Pdf or the `UIWebView` is cutting it.

PDF Function

```
func createPDFfromUIView(aView: UIView) //-> UIImage
{

    let pdfData = NSMutableData()
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, aView.frame, nil)
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage()
    let pdfContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    aView.layer.renderInContext(pdfContext!)
    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();

    let documentsDirectory: NSString = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask,true)[0] as NSString

    let dataPath = documentsDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent("/JamaWEpdf")

    if (!NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(dataPath as String)) {
       do{
           try NSFileManager.defaultManager().createDirectoryAtPath(dataPath, withIntermediateDirectories: false, attributes: nil)
       }
       catch _{}
   }

   let filePath = "\(dataPath)entry\(entry1.entryId)pdf.pdf"
   pdfData.writeToFile(filePath, atomically: true)

   let webView = UIWebView()
   webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)))
   webView.frame = self.view.frame
   self.view.addSubview(webView)
}
```

I don't know if my approach is right. The `UIView` size is w: 2480 h: 3508.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was generating the view programmatically so when this line was executed:

```
UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, aView.frame, nil)
```

the frame was not rendered or something. So instead I use a CGRect with the size I wanted and it work:

```
UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 2480, height: 3508), nil)
```